# Why do these two pieces of code have different complexities?

Tags: python, compare, complexity-theory

Both of these pieces of code do the same thing, which is they check if the words in the list `magazine_words` are sufficient to make up the message dictated by the words in the list `note_words` . However the first piece of code takes a lot more time to execute, which doesn't let it run for large inputs. Why is that? Since both solutions use single for-loops, shouldn't they have the same complexity, i.e. take about the same time to run?

First solution:

```
lengths = input().split ()
m = int(lengths[0])
n = int(lengths [1])
magazine_words = input ().split()
note_words = input ().split()
def checkMagazine(m,n,magazine_words,note_words):
  flag = "Yes"
  for ind in range (n):
    if not (note_words[ind] in magazine_words):
      flag = "No"
      break
    else:
      magazine_words.remove(note_words[ind])
  return flag
print (checkMagazine(m,n,magazine_words,note_words))
```

Second solution:

````
def ransom_note(magazine, ransom):
    rc = {} # dict of word: count of that word in the note
    for word in ransom:
        if word not in rc:
            rc[word] = 0
        rc[word] += 1

    for word in magazine:
        if word in rc:
            rc[word] -= 1
            if rc[word] == 0:
                del rc[word]
                if not rc:
                    return True
    return False



m, n = map(int, input().strip().split(' '))
magazine = input().strip().split(' ')
ransom = input().strip().split(' ')
answer = ransom_note(magazine, ransom)
if(answer):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")```
````

Answer (score 1):

`magazine_words.remove(note_words[ind])` is secretly another loop - this has to loop through all of `magazine_words` until it finds `note_words[ind]`, each time you call it.